# Pandas run expression to filter out columns with dynamic list of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of columns that a user will provide at runtime. Because of this, the list is subject to change.

I want to drop all rows from a DataFrame that have a value set for **ALL** columns in that list of columns. How would I do this efficiently within pandas? Would the best approach be to just simply iterate through, or is there a more "pandas" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[1,5,6],
                   'C':[1,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  1  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

cols = ['A','B','C']
val = 1

print (df[cols] == val)
       A      B      C
0   True   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False

mask = ~(df[cols] == val).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
```

Comment: Ah, smart! This is exactly the sort of thing I needed. Thank you!